# How does same origin policy work in IndexDB for local html / file system (file:///)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I'm creating an app that will run offline but in the browser in a transpiled HTML file. It only has to work in recent version of chrome. The url bar will show something like file:///Users/.../app.html

I've done some rudimentary tests in my environment and the browser seems to remember my indexDB. Is this correct? Will this work? How does it know which "domain" to restrict the app to?

Comment: If it works... that's a bug ;p Well, at least for localStorage they decided that they would consider **every** document to be its own domain, and thus even two windows with the same document shouldn't share the Storage area. So follwing this logic, indexedDB should also treat `file://`  as not same-domain, but that wouldn't be [their first bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=780360) in this area.

Comment: @Kaiido I hope they don't fix it if it's a bug, it's a cool feature.